# Aiogram, python, номер телефона

Tags: python, aiogram

Нужно запросить номер телефона из инлайн-кнопки и обработать принятие номера телефона

```
nomer_key = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
nomer_key.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Отправить номер", callback_data="nomer", request_contact=True))    
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Нужен номер для связи.", reply_markup=nomer_key)
```

Вот как обработать не знаю, просто вывести полученный телефон

Answer (score 0):

В Telegram боте невозможно получить номер телефона, используя Inline Keyboard, но можно использовать Reply Keyboard Markup

Чтобы обработать клавиатуру, мы должны использовать ContentType

```py
# keyboards.py
async def contact_keyboard():
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    first_button = KeyboardButton(text=_(" Отправить"), request_contact=True)
    markup.add(first_button)
    return markup


# handlers.py
@dp.message_handler(Command("contact"))
async def share_number(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Нажмите на кнопку ниже, чтобы отправить контакт", reply_markup=await contact_keyboard())

@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.CONTACT)
async def get_contact(message: types.Message):
    contact = message.contact
    await message.answer(f"Спасибо, {contact.full_name}.\n"
                         f"Ваш номер {contact.phone_number} был получен",
                         reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```